# c++ regular expressions: how to catch vector of submatches

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, cookies, boost

Let's suppose it's ECMAScript, regexp of c++11 or boost::xpressive
On input I have a string in format: `key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3` so on, so a regular expression for this would be

```
((w+)\=(w+)\;)*((\w)+\=(\w)+)\;?
```

I want to get all keys and values into two std::vector< std::string >
So submatch 1,2,3,4 have all what I need. And there is problem - likely \1 is an array. I don't see any interface how can I get neither in c++ regex nor in boost::xpressive. Probably it's here but is not so obvious.

Comment: a) Are your sure that no key contains `=`, no value contains `;`, that there are no whitespaces that don´t belong to key/value, etc.etc.? Else, everything gets more complicated. b) Why regex? While it may be bit shorter in code, to find the first `=`, call substr, the same for `;`, and everything in a big loop is <10 lines too. Not that much difference, and apparently less problems.

Comment: Have you looked at a [regex_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_iterator/)?

Comment: Yes, surely I'm sure :) I just tried to not overload community with really complex reg-exp. I try to parse Set-Cookie: http header. Surely I can use token iterator, but this way I will end up with writing RL descending parser. I've been hoping to remain lazy and let the libraries to make work for me.

Comment: I'd certainly use Boost Spirit for the job

Comment: Are you sure you're parsing the [`Set-Cookie` header](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.1)? This looks closer to the [`Cookie` header](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-4.2.1). Cookies are easily undestimated...

Comment: @dev_null I had been waiting for your response. As an exercise I had already taken up a partial implementation of a proper cookie parser. I think it would have been a shame not to post it after all, so see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29571889/85371). Hope you enjoy it!

Answer (score 3):

Although you never came back on the precise nature of the requirements, I want to show you what I came up with to /just/ parse the `Set-Cookie` response header as described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109 §4.2.2 "Set-Cookie Syntax"

Note that

- This is meant as a direct translation of the specs.
- I tried to keep strict to the specs (regarding date format, number format, case sensitivity etc.).
- Note also that this draws on extensive experience with the Boost Spirit library, so it's likely not for everyone to translate the specs into working code this way
- Also, by sticking to the specs, many real life cookies would be rejected (e.g. for lack of space after `;`). Making it real-life proof would take some more tweaking (specifically, changing the skipper type and designating sub-parser-expressions as `lexeme`s
- Finally, the clincher: this is only **one of the RFCs**. There are other versions, and they specify variations that aren't covered here. In real life, HTTP clients have to resort to heuristics to perfect the art of deciphering cookies. They routinely switch to entirely different parsing code depending on versions.

  > **Anecdote**: Just today I traced a bug in our software to cookies being swallowed by OpenJDK 6. Without exception. You guessed it: due to unsupported features. Of course, Java 6 is old, but we're not going to drop support for it until our next release. So... we write more parsing code.

### Variant 1: unbounded attribute-list

Here's the most versatile version of the code, in which the AST contains a vector of variant attributes (as the grammar implies):

```
using expires_av   = attribute<attr::expires, rfc1123date>;
using max_age_av   = attribute<attr::max_age, int>;
using domain_av    = attribute<attr::domain>;
using path_av      = attribute<attr::path>;
using secure_av    = attribute<attr::secure, void>;
using httponly_av  = attribute<attr::httponly, void>;
using extension_av = attribute<attr::extension>;

using cookie_av = boost::variant<
        expires_av,
        max_age_av,
        domain_av,
        path_av,
        secure_av,
        httponly_av,
        extension_av
    >;

struct cookie_pair {
    std::string name, value;
};

struct cookie {
    cookie_pair pair;
    std::list<cookie_av> attributes;
};
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8164b0c995a6417c)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>

namespace http {
    class datetime {
        using clock = boost::local_time::local_sec_clock;
        boost::local_time::local_date_time m_dt;
      public:
        datetime() : m_dt(clock::local_time(boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr())) {
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, datetime const& o) {
            std::ostream imbued(os.rdbuf());
            imbued.imbue(std::locale(imbued.getloc(), new boost::local_time::local_time_facet("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")));
            imbued << o.m_dt;
            return os;
        }

        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, datetime& o) {
            std::istream imbued(is.rdbuf());
            imbued.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new boost::local_time::local_time_input_facet("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")));
            imbued >> o.m_dt;
            return is;
        }
    };
}

namespace ast {
    using rfc1123date = http::datetime; // rfc1123 formatting

    namespace attr {
        struct expires   { static constexpr char const* name() { return "expires";   } };
        struct max_age   { static constexpr char const* name() { return "max-age";   } };
        struct domain    { static constexpr char const* name() { return "domain";    } };
        struct path      { static constexpr char const* name() { return "path";      } };
        struct secure    { static constexpr char const* name() { return "secure";    } };
        struct httponly  { static constexpr char const* name() { return "httponly";  } };
        struct extension { static constexpr char const* name() { return "extension"; } };
    }

    template <typename tag, typename V = std::string>
    struct attribute {
        V value;
        attribute(V value = {}) : value(std::move(value)) {}
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, attribute const& attr) {
            return os << "[ " << tag::name() << "=" << attr.value << " ]";
        }
    };

    template <typename tag>
    struct attribute<tag, void> {
        //attribute(bool = true) {};
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, attribute const&) {
            return os << "[ attribute: present ]";
        }
    };

    using expires_av   = attribute<attr::expires, rfc1123date>;
    using max_age_av   = attribute<attr::max_age, int>;
    using domain_av    = attribute<attr::domain>;
    using path_av      = attribute<attr::path>;
    using secure_av    = attribute<attr::secure, void>;
    using httponly_av  = attribute<attr::httponly, void>;
    using extension_av = attribute<attr::extension>;

    using cookie_av = boost::variant<
            expires_av,
            max_age_av,
            domain_av,
            path_av,
            secure_av,
            httponly_av,
            extension_av
        >;

    struct cookie_pair {
        std::string name, value;
    };

    struct cookie {
        cookie_pair pair;
        std::list<cookie_av> attributes;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::cookie_pair,
        (std::string, name)
        (std::string, value)
    )

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::cookie,
        (ast::cookie_pair, pair)
        (std::list<ast::cookie_av>, attributes)
    )

namespace ast {
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::list<cookie_av> const&v) {
        os << "{";
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<cookie_av>(os, "; "));
        return os << "}";
    }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, cookie_pair const&v) { return os << boost::fusion::as_vector(v); }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, cookie      const&v) { return os << boost::fusion::as_vector(v); }
}

template <typename It>
struct set_cookie : qi::grammar<It, ast::cookie()> {
    set_cookie() : set_cookie::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;
        using boost::proto::deep_copy;

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // RFC2616 2.2 token
#define RFC_CTLs "\x01-\x1f\x7f"
        constexpr char DQUOTE = '"';
        token = +(~char_(RFC_CTLs /*separators:*/ "()<>@,;:\\\"/[]?={} \t") - '\0');

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // RFC6265 4.1.1. Syntax (set-cookie)

        set_cookie_header = no_case["set-cookie: "] >> set_cookie_string;
        set_cookie_string = cookie_pair >> *("; " >> cookie_av);
        cookie_pair       = cookie_name >> '=' >> cookie_value;
        cookie_name       = token;
        auto cookie_octet = deep_copy(char_("\x21" "\x23-\x2B" "\x2D-\x3A" "\x3C-\x5B" "\x5D-\x7E"));
        cookie_value      = *cookie_octet | (DQUOTE >> *cookie_octet >> DQUOTE);
        //                     ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
        //                     ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
        //                     ; and backslash

        cookie_av         = expires_av
                          | max_age_av
                          | domain_av
                          | path_av
                          | secure_av
                          | httponly_av
                          | extension_av
                          ;
        expires_av        = no_case["expires="] >> sane_cookie_date;
        sane_cookie_date  = stream; // TODO <rfc1123_date, defined in [RFC2616], Section 3.3.1>
        max_age_av        = no_case["max-age="] >> !char_('0') >> uint_;
        //                     ; In practice, both expires_av and max_age_av
        //                     ; are limited to dates representable by the
        //                     ; user agent.
        // non_zero_digit    = %x31-39
        //                     ; digits 1 through 9
        domain_av         = no_case["domain="] >> domain_value;
        domain_value      = raw [ (alpha >> *(alpha|digit|'-')) % '.'];
        //                     ; defined in [RFC1034], Section 3.5, as
        //                     ; enhanced by [RFC1123], Section 2.1
        path_av           = no_case["path="] >> path_value;
        path_value        = *(~char_(RFC_CTLs ";") - '\0'); //  <any CHAR except CTLs or ";">
        secure_av         = no_case["secure"]   >> attr(ast::secure_av{});
        httponly_av       = no_case["httponly"] >> attr(ast::httponly_av{});
        extension_av      = as_string [*(~char_(RFC_CTLs ";") - '\0')]; // <any CHAR except CTLs or ";">

        start = set_cookie_header;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (start)
                (set_cookie_header) (set_cookie_string)
                (cookie_pair) (cookie_name) (cookie_value) (token)

                (cookie_av)
                (expires_av) (sane_cookie_date)
                (max_age_av)
                (domain_av)  (domain_value)
                (path_av)    (path_value)
                (secure_av)
                (httponly_av)
                (extension_av)
            );
#undef RFC_CTLs
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, ast::cookie()>       start;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()>       token, cookie_name, cookie_value, domain_value, path_value;

    qi::rule<It, ast::cookie()>       set_cookie_header, set_cookie_string;
    qi::rule<It, ast::cookie_pair()>  cookie_pair;

    qi::rule<It, ast::cookie_av()>    cookie_av;

    qi::rule<It, ast::expires_av()>   expires_av;
    qi::rule<It, ast::rfc1123date()>  sane_cookie_date;

    qi::rule<It, ast::max_age_av()>   max_age_av; // non_zero_digit;
    qi::rule<It, ast::domain_av()>    domain_av;
    qi::rule<It, ast::path_av()>      path_av;

    qi::rule<It, ast::secure_av()>    secure_av;
    qi::rule<It, ast::httponly_av()>  httponly_av;
    qi::rule<It, ast::extension_av()> extension_av;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    for (std::string const s : {
            "Set-Cookie: name=value",
            "Set-Cookie: name=value; Path=/; Domain=domain.com",
            "set-cookie: name=value; path=/; domain=domain.com",

            //// not actually rfc 6265 conformant:
            //"Set-Cookie: name=value;path=/;domain=domain.com",

            // actually a wednesday:
            "Set-Cookie: name=value; path=/; domain=.mydomain.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-2070 00:00:10 GMT; comment=no_comment"
            })
    {
        It f = s.begin(), l = s.end();
        std::cout << "Parsing '" << s << "'\n";

        ast::cookie cookie;
        bool ok = qi::parse(f,l,set_cookie<It>(),cookie);

        if (ok) {
            std::cout << " -- Parse success: " << cookie << "\n";
        }
        else
            std::cout << " -- Parse failure\n";

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << " -- Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

### Variant 2: fixed optional attribute set

Here's a version that might be more convenient in real life. Because, though the grammar doesn't limit say, `Expires` or `HttpOnly` attributes to appearing 1 time only, in practice it wouldn't make sense to have repeated attributes of these kind. So, here's a variant that just parses into an aggregate of `optional<>` attributes instead

```
using domain_av = string_attribute;
using path_av = string_attribute;
using extension_av = string_attribute;

struct cookie_av {
    optional<expires_av> expires;
    optional<max_age_av> max_age;
    optional<domain_av> domain;
    optional<path_av> path;
    bool secure   = false;
    bool httponly = false;
    optional<extension_av> extension;
};

struct cookie_pair {
    std::string name, value;
};

struct cookie {
    cookie_pair pair;
    cookie_av   attributes;
};
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99bac03bfe3b3ac7)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>

namespace http {
    class datetime {
        using clock = boost::local_time::local_sec_clock;
        boost::local_time::local_date_time m_dt;
      public:
        datetime() : m_dt(clock::local_time(boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr())) {
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, datetime const& o) {
            std::ostream imbued(os.rdbuf());
            imbued.imbue(std::locale(imbued.getloc(), new boost::local_time::local_time_facet("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")));
            imbued << o.m_dt;
            return os;
        }

        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, datetime& o) {
            std::istream imbued(is.rdbuf());
            imbued.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new boost::local_time::local_time_input_facet("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")));
            imbued >> o.m_dt;
            return is;
        }
    };
}

namespace ast {
    using boost::optional;
    using rfc1123date = http::datetime; // rfc1123 formatting

    struct expires_av {
        rfc1123date date;
        expires_av(rfc1123date date = {}) : date(date) {}
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, expires_av const& attr) {
            return os << "[ expires_av: " << attr.date << " ]";
        }
    };

    struct max_age_av {
        unsigned age;
        max_age_av(unsigned age = {}) : age(age) {}
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, max_age_av const& attr) {
            return os << "[ max_age_av: " << attr.age << " ]";
        }
    };
    struct string_attribute {
        std::string value;
        string_attribute(std::string value = "") : value(std::move(value)) {}
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, string_attribute const& attr) {
            return os << "[ string_attribute: " << attr.value << " ]";
        }
    };
    using domain_av = string_attribute;
    using path_av = string_attribute;
    using extension_av = string_attribute;

    struct cookie_av {
        optional<expires_av> expires;
        optional<max_age_av> max_age;
        optional<domain_av> domain;
        optional<path_av> path;
        bool secure   = false;
        bool httponly = false;
        optional<extension_av> extension;
    };

    struct cookie_pair {
        std::string name, value;
    };

    struct cookie {
        cookie_pair pair;
        cookie_av   attributes;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::cookie_av,
        (optional<ast::expires_av>,expires)
        (optional<ast::max_age_av>,max_age)
        (optional<ast::domain_av>,domain)
        (optional<ast::path_av>,path)
        (bool,secure)
        (bool,httponly)
        (optional<ast::extension_av>,extension)
    )

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::cookie_pair,
        (std::string, name)
        (std::string, value)
    )

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::cookie,
        (ast::cookie_pair, pair)
        (ast::cookie_av, attributes)
    )

namespace ast {
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, cookie_av   const&v) { return os << boost::fusion::as_vector(v); }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, cookie_pair const&v) { return os << boost::fusion::as_vector(v); }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, cookie      const&v) { return os << boost::fusion::as_vector(v); }
}

template <typename It>
struct set_cookie : qi::grammar<It, ast::cookie()> {
    set_cookie() : set_cookie::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;
        using boost::proto::deep_copy;

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // RFC2616 2.2 token
#define RFC_CTLs "\x01-\x1f\x7f"
        constexpr char DQUOTE = '"';
        token = +(~char_(RFC_CTLs /*separators:*/ "()<>@,;:\\\"/[]?={} \t") - '\0');

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // RFC6265 4.1.1. Syntax (set-cookie)

        set_cookie_header = no_case["set-cookie: "] >> set_cookie_string;
        set_cookie_string = cookie_pair >> -attributes;
        cookie_pair       = cookie_name >> '=' >> cookie_value;
        cookie_name       = token;
        auto cookie_octet = deep_copy(char_("\x21" "\x23-\x2B" "\x2D-\x3A" "\x3C-\x5B" "\x5D-\x7E"));
        cookie_value      = *cookie_octet | (DQUOTE >> *cookie_octet >> DQUOTE);
        //                     ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
        //                     ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
        //                     ; and backslash

        attributes        = ("; " >> expires_av)
                          ^ ("; " >> max_age_av)
                          ^ ("; " >> domain_av)
                          ^ ("; " >> path_av)
                          ^ ("; " >> secure_av)
                          ^ ("; " >> httponly_av)
                          ^ ("; " >> extension_av)
                          ;
        expires_av        = no_case["expires="] >> sane_cookie_date;
        sane_cookie_date  = stream; // TODO <rfc1123_date, defined in [RFC2616], Section 3.3.1>
        max_age_av        = no_case["max-age="] >> !char_('0') >> uint_;
        //                     ; In practice, both expires_av and max_age_av
        //                     ; are limited to dates representable by the
        //                     ; user agent.
        // non_zero_digit    = %x31-39
        //                     ; digits 1 through 9
        domain_av         = no_case["domain="] >> domain_value;
        domain_value      = raw [ (alpha >> *(alpha|digit|'-')) % '.'];
        //                     ; defined in [RFC1034], Section 3.5, as
        //                     ; enhanced by [RFC1123], Section 2.1
        path_av           = no_case["path="] >> path_value;
        path_value        = *(~char_(RFC_CTLs ";") - '\0'); //  <any CHAR except CTLs or ";">
        secure_av         = no_case["secure"]   >> attr(true);
        httponly_av       = no_case["httponly"] >> attr(true);
        extension_av      = as_string [*(~char_(RFC_CTLs ";") - '\0')]; // <any CHAR except CTLs or ";">

        start = set_cookie_header;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (start)
                (set_cookie_header) (set_cookie_string)
                (cookie_pair) (cookie_name) (cookie_value) (token)

                (attributes)
                (expires_av) (sane_cookie_date)
                (max_age_av)
                (domain_av)  (domain_value)
                (path_av)    (path_value)
                (secure_av)
                (httponly_av)
                (extension_av)
            );
#undef RFC_CTLs
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, ast::cookie()>       start;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()>       token, cookie_name, cookie_value, domain_value, path_value;

    qi::rule<It, ast::cookie()>       set_cookie_header, set_cookie_string;
    qi::rule<It, ast::cookie_pair()>  cookie_pair;

    qi::rule<It, ast::cookie_av()>    attributes;

    qi::rule<It, ast::expires_av()>   expires_av;
    qi::rule<It, ast::rfc1123date()>  sane_cookie_date;

    qi::rule<It, ast::max_age_av()>   max_age_av; // non_zero_digit;
    qi::rule<It, ast::domain_av()>    domain_av;
    qi::rule<It, ast::path_av()>      path_av;

    qi::rule<It, bool()>              secure_av, httponly_av;
    qi::rule<It, ast::extension_av()> extension_av;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    for (std::string const s : {
            "Set-Cookie: name=value",
            "Set-Cookie: name=value; Path=/; Domain=domain.com",
            "set-cookie: name=value; path=/; domain=domain.com",
            //// not actually rfc 6265 conformant:
            //"Set-Cookie: name=value;path=/;domain=domain.com",

            // actually a wednesday:
            "Set-Cookie: name=value; path=/; domain=.mydomain.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-2070 00:00:10 GMT; comment=no_comment"
            })
    {
        It f = s.begin(), l = s.end();
        std::cout << "Parsing '" << s << "'\n";

        ast::cookie cookie;
        bool ok = qi::parse(f,l,set_cookie<It>(),cookie);

        if (ok) {
            std::cout << " -- Parse success: " << cookie << "\n";
        }
        else
            std::cout << " -- Parse failure\n";

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << " -- Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

### Summary

**Cookie parsing is library material**. It may seem trivial. But you have to deal with a plethora of (legacy) RFCs and even more implementation quirks.

Cookies are not trivial.

Comment: I am working on a cookie parser for boost and am trying to learn boost::spirit better. I have gone through the docs and I think I have gotten the hand on the grammar. I just had a few questions:
1. For the datetime I have written the other formats for rfc850 and asctime but the problem is obviously that I just want to parse the date as either rfc1123, rfc850, or asctime, but store the underlying data in the same struct.
2. Was wondering how to handle errors in parsing for malicious inputs?
I am new to the boost community and am self taught so any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: any mentorship/assistance you can provide would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: @WarrenNiles I'm happy to review code or ask specific questions. Also, existing libraries may be of inspiration

Comment: Basically, I am trying to build a cookie parser using specifications from:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie

For stuff like the "SameSite=" field there are 3 accepted values: Strict, Lax, None. Want to store as an unsigned int, but not sure the "spirit" way to do it.

Also stuff like __Secure- and __Host- Prefix which is optional, but places restrictions on other fields.

Comment: @WarrenNiles I'm aware of the cookie specs. They are very broad. To the specific questions: consider asking them - this is a Q&A site after all.

Comment: @WarrenNiles To the enumeration: [use symbols, e.g.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4acc7109f11baee0). The _semantics_ of the prefixes is not part of the grammar, so validate that outside the grammar.