# Best way to parse cookies with Boost.Beast

Tags: c++, boost, boost-beast

What is the best way to parse/iterate cookies with Boost.Beast?

The method by Vinnie Falco does not works:

```
http::request<empty_body> req;
...
// Print each cookie in the request
for(auto param : http::param_list(req[field::cookie]))
    std::cout << "Cookie '" << param.first << "' has value '" << param.second << "'\n";
```

https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/1425#issuecomment-459985055

`req[field::cookie]` returns something like "MyCookie=123" but `http::param_list()` requires semicolon in the front, like ";MyCookie=123".

Of course, I can parse/iterate cookies by writing my own code, but may be there is a common solution for such thing? I just need to extract value of a specific cookie.

Answer (score 0):

This has not been implemented in Beast, and it is far from trivial do, since https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265 is quite involved.

See e.g. the linked issue: https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/1425

Now, to my own surprise I have already written an RFC6265 set-cookie parser
using just Boost for [Stackoverflow in
2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471089/c-regular-expressions-how-to-catch-vector-of-submatches/29571889#29571889).
Mind you, that **only** gives you a parser. A functional "cookie-jar"
implementation would add ways to usefully query them.

The whole answer is worth a read - includes examples of where the subject
becomes more complex than you might expect. I whole-heartedly agree with the
summary I wrote back then:

> Cookie parsing is library material. It may seem trivial. But you have to deal
> with a plethora of (legacy) RFCs and even more implementation quirks.
>
> Cookies are not trivial.

I think [libcurl has a cookie-jar implementation](https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html) that I would trust. I suppose other libraries might (cpprestsdk, cppnetlib?).